# Call user by name when typing text in the TinyMCE editor using the %name% PHP + Mysql tag

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

Hello I apologize for being a layman on the subject.

But I am setting up a messaging system with PHP + TinyMCE editor and mysql.

My question is how to create a function that allows me to call all users by "Name" using a wildcard of type% name% where this wildcard can display the user's name when making a query in the MYSQL users table and pulling the names in the field "Name" of the users table.

My intention is to make PHP display the user name inside the text when I type anything and add this wildcard in the text

Ex: Hello %name% I saw here that your subscription expired on the %expiryday% to renew your access click on the link %linkpayment%

In summary the wildcards
%name%
%expiryday%
%linkpayment%

They will be replaced by the person's name, due date and payment link that are in the users table by pulling the fields "name", "expiration day" and "link payment"

I would add these wildcards to my text and when I click submit I would make a SELECT call in Mysql using While and turning these wildcards into variables that will display the above mentioned data.

Would anyone have an example of how I can make this part of the wildcards?

Thank you in advance and apologize if the question is not interesting.

A practical example would be this here:
https://docs.mautic.org/en/setup/variables

Comment: It will depend if you want this to be replace on-the-fly whilst the user is typing in their content, OR after you click Submit and the content is saved and then processed?

Comment: Hello, how is everything? Thanks for the question. In this case, I will submit the tinyMCE editor form to a post.php in this post there will be a function that will receive the post, parse the tags %name%, %linkpayment%, %dateexpiration%

Comment: Turn this into a kind of query inside the PHP while and pull the data from the field "name", "linkpayment" and "dateexpiration" from the users table of the MySQL database.

These tags will show along with the sent message, the person's name, payment link and expiration date,

Comment: I've seen this on a PHP system called Mautic. I wanted to implement it on my system. But I didn't see anything on the internet talking about it.